# Add key/value pair to returned mongoose object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, stripe.js

I have code that retrieves a Mongoose object and then uses the `stripeCustomerId` (stored in the document) to retrieve the Stripe `customer` object (via nodejs stripe).  I then want to attach the stripe `customer` object to my Mongoose object.

```
exports.getPlatformByCId = (cId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Platform.find({ clientId: cId }).then(response => {
            let user = response[0];
            stripe.customers.retrieve(user.stripeCustomerId, (err, stripeCust) => {                
                if(err) {
                    user["stripeCustomer"] = null;
                } else {
                    user["stripeCustomer"] = stripeCust;
                }
                resolve(user);
            })
        }).catch(err => {
            if(err) {
                if(err.error !== 'not_found') {
                    resolve(err);
                } else {
                    reject(err);
                }
            }
        })
    })
}
```

I also tried `user.stripeCustomer = stripeCust` I am getting the mongoose object back where it needs to go, but `stripeCustomer` is not a part of that object!  I have verified that `stripeCust`is, in fact, returning the data I'm expecting it to.

Any guidance?  I'm wondering if the Schema is somehow protected, and maybe there's a mongoose way to fix this?

Comment: The `user` variable is just data. Is the user variable an Array or an Object?

Comment: The response is an array in which I assign user the first object in the response.  I've verified user is, in fact, an object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Disconect the object from mongoose. When making the query use the `lean()` method of mongoose to get a JSON object. Then you can add keys to it.

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

Comment: Thank you! I was unaware that mongoose objects cannot be modified like normal objects. :)

Comment: Is there any way to add a `key` afterwards though? I'm using `find` to get a `Document`. But I cannot use `lean` because I'd like to call `set`. Upon `set`, I'd like to add a `key` to the Object version of the `doc` - but not the `doc` itself. Is this possible?

Comment: @user2402616 you can use .toObject() on the returned mongoose document